# Why submenus in css dropdown menu are not visible?

Tags: css, visibility

I have just installed a css dropdown menu here: http://ilke.evaistanbul.com.tr/

The menus have submenus. But they are not visible. They seem like to be overridden by some upper layer elements:

Hovering mouse on the menu:

[image]

Normal state of the menu:

[image]

What is the reason that the submenus are not visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you remove the overflow:hidden of the .lavaLampBottomStyle, it will show.

Answer (score 0):

On your CSS,

```
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
display: none;
}
```

You need to have this as `display:block` so-

```
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```